# How to create rounded broken oval in Sketch

Tags: shapes, sketch-app

[image]

How to create such shape in Sketch?

I've tried using the oval tool, then tried subtract. I can create it with a pen tool, but it is a lot of work. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create an oval with a thick border.
2. Create one rectangle, placing on top of the oval (make the height a little less than the height of the oval).
3. Select both the oval and rectangle, then select 'intersect'.
4. Use the scissors tool delete the straight edges of the new shape.

You should also ensure the "Ends" of your borders are rounded within border settings (the cog in the upper right section of "Borders").

Here is the above, visualised: [image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was just going to suggest another way but yours seems much more convenient.